# Typescript typed function from key value object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an object like

```
const lookup = {
  key1: object1,
  key2: object2,
  key3: object3
}
```

And i need to create function which accept key(key1/key2...) as first param and
typeof object1 as second.

And if i use foo(key1, {}) i have to specify only params of selected object (object1)

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your question, could you try to write it in a different way?  What is the meaning of `i have to specify only params of selected object` ?

Comment: Object1 and object2 have different keys (for example only name and title) and if i call foo('object1', {name: ''}) i have to specify keys of this object

Comment: The main approach is to use generics: ```function foo<K extends keyof typeof lookup>(key: K, obj: (typeof lookup)[K]) {}```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commenter above suggested a solution with generics

```
function foo<K extends keyof typeof lookup>(key: K, obj: (typeof lookup)[K]) {}
```

Comment: If it worked, could you explain a bit more how it does and what it do ? So it may helps other people that face the same problem